# select_tag results do not save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

For the life of me I cannot figure out why the result of this select tag will not save when posted. I'm not using attr_accessible.

view:

```
<%= f.label :kind, "1-bug 2-mod 3-new 4-other" %><br />
<%= select_tag :kind, options_for_select(SiteCare::KIND, :kind) %>
```

site_care model:

```
  KIND = [["1 Bug",1],
          ["2 Modification",2],
          ["3 New",3],
          ["4 Other",4]]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any attr_accessible in your model? (or attr_protected)

Comment: Is that attribute accessible? Do you get any warning/error in your server logs? Could you log the value of params from the controller and paste that here?

Comment: Hey, @JesseWolgamott and @Dogbert attr_accessible. I just edited the question to address this and then found you asked the question. You guys are fast!

Comment: BTW, whoever gave me a minus 1 on the question, you ought to have the integrity to leave a comment why!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should be using `select` instead of `select_tag` like this

```
<%= f.label :kind, "1-bug 2-mod 3-new 4-other" %><br />
<%= f.select :kind, SiteCare::KIND %>
```

then only it will bind with the object `@site_care` because `f.select` will pass it as the first arguement for `select` tag.

Comment: Thanks @rubyprince. I'll accept the answer as soon as the system lets me.